# screensaver lock won't release

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

I have my Ubuntu 12 desktop set to lock after a time period-- this works fine, but when I go to unlock it sometimes (usually only after leaving it locked overnight) won't come out of the locked state-- the lock dialog goes away but it still shows the image from the locked screen (usually a picture from variety, which I use as a background switcher).

I can Ctrl-Alt-F1 into a command prompt, and the processes seem to be fine, so I think the system is fine, it's just the lock app (or whatever it is) that might be screwed up.

How can I diagnose this? Is there a `kill` command I can issue from the command prompt to disable the lock view?

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04, you could try `gnome-screensaver-commands -d`, to deactivate it.

(This is outdated as of 14.04)